# How to make individual task as function python

Tags: python, mysql

I have this python code which let's me insert content from an excel file to a db, it works but I want to make each individual task into functions eg connecting to db or opening the excel woorkbook

```
import xlrd
import MySQLdb

#open workbook
book = xlrd.open_workbook("path")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(1)

#connect to db
database = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "password", db = "test")

#get cursor

cursor = database.cursor()

#query

query = """ INSERT into employee(fname, mname, lname, age) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"""

#create loop

for r in range (1, sheet.nrows):
    fname = sheet.cell(r,0).value
    mname = sheet.cell(r,1).value
    lname = sheet.cell(r,2).value
    age = sheet.cell(r,3).value

#values
    values = (fname,mname,lname,age)

#execute query
    cursor.execute(query, values)

#close
cursor.close()

#comit the transaction
database.commit()

#close db
database.close()

#print result
print ("")
print ("done!")
print ("")
columns = str(sheet.ncols)
rows = str(sheet.nrows)

print("columns " + columns + " row " + rows + " to MySQL")
```

tried something like this (function) but only insert the last row of my excel file

```
import MySQLdb

def con(datab, query, values):
        database = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="pass", db=datab)
        cursor = database.cursor()
        df = cursor.execute(query, values)
        database.commit()
        database.close()
        return df
```

then this

```
import dbex
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook("path")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(1)

query = """ INSERT into employee(first_name, mname, lname, age) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"""

for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
        fname = sheet.cell(r, 0).value
        mname = sheet.cell(r, 1).value
        lname = sheet.cell(r, 2).value
        age = sheet.cell(r, 3).value

values = (fname, mname, lname, age)

rn = dbex.con("test", query, values)

print(r)
```

how do I write the function so it inserts all rows from excel file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `values` and `rn = dbex.con("test", query, values)` are outside of the for loop in the 2nd example.. you will have to run the command to insert each row otherwise it will only hold the last values from the for loop.

```
for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    fname = sheet.cell(r, 0).value
    mname = sheet.cell(r, 1).value
    lname = sheet.cell(r, 2).value
    age = sheet.cell(r, 3).value

    values = (fname, mname, lname, age)
    rn = dbex.con("test", query, values)

    print(r)
```

You can create a function for this like so.

```
def add_excel_data(sheet, query):
    """Takes in an excel sheet and adds each rod to a Database"""

    try:
        for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
                fname = sheet.cell(r, 0).value
                mname = sheet.cell(r, 1).value
                lname = sheet.cell(r, 2).value
                age = sheet.cell(r, 3).value

                values = (fname, mname, lname, age)

                rn = dbex.con("test", query, values)

                print(r)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Cool,, does it work?  If it does, please accept the correct answer!